# Unable to get Textillate.js to work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using code from online demos to get the library up and running but even then textilate.js is just not working. I have checked everything I can think off, multiple times.

By not working I mean that there is no animation effect upon the text.

**In the error console it states: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $" .**

the actual URL is: [www.econengines.com](http://www.econengines.com).

Here is the code (including dependencies):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">

<div class="tlt">
    <p>Each of these letters will animate.</p>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tlt').textillate({ in : {
                shuffle: false,
                sync: true
            },
            out: {
                effect: 'fadeOutRightBig',
                shuffle: false,
                sync: true
            },
            loop: true
        });
    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lettering.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="textillate.js"></script>
```

And a snapshot of the FTP file:

[image: FTP]

I am using a web framework called MaterializeCSS and I did try disabling that as well as the MaterializeCSS js script, but it had not effect.

I thank you for your input and attention in advance :-)

Comment: I copied your code in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sajn8yL4/) and it is working just fine. Or this isn't the expected result? If it is, please check the console for errors.

Comment: Could you specify what *just not working* means?

Comment: Thank you for your response @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo ! I updated the description to include answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a look at your source code and I realized that you are calling the `$(document).ready()` function before loading the JS libraries.

You need to move this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lettering.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="textillate.js"></script>
```

and place it **BEFORE** this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tlt').textillate({ 
        in : {
            shuffle: false,
            sync: true
        },
        out: {
            effect: 'fadeOutRightBig',
            shuffle: false,
            sync: true
        },
        loop: true
    });
});
```

Rememeber to always load the libraries and dependencieas before using them.

Comment: It works! I now have the Textillate effect on certain text. However ... the `center` alignment isn't working on the text in question, when viewed on mobile. It's like the grid system isn't working right.... any work around?

Comment: I think that you should ask a new question here with that specific problem. That people who knows more in that matter can help you.